# Kernel Panic - not syncing :Attempted to kill init

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kernel

I am facing this problem on my Debian5. I am running this server in Virtual Box.I have four os in this machine. But in this server only I get this message when I boot .

```
run init: /sbin/init : Permission Denied 
Kernel Panic - not syncing : Attemped to kill init
```

Can anyone help on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow it can't run /sbin/init maybe some filesystem error or the init is deleted/corrupted.

Try to boot the machine with LiveCD and mount the filesystem and check /sbin/init.

Comment: Actually my server is running in virtual box,, Is it possible to use the liveCD in Virtual box..

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Actually I have only server.Vdi image .. Can it be mounted through liveCD...

Comment: You attach a LiveCD iso image to the virtual machine and boot that, like a phisical machine.

Comment: Thanks, I have successfully mounted the file system. How can I solve the problem now...?

Comment: Check if the init is there, runnable, etc...

Answer (score 1):

This setting helped for me: in VirtualBox, where you set the optical drive of the guest machine, you enabled some drive of the host's. If that's a virtual drive, don't enable Passthrough option.